# No matching overloaded function found C++ TEMPLATE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Recurvise call C++ template function with Variable template

```
void int void foo()
{

}

template <typename T, typename ...U> void foo()
{
    foo<U...>();
}

int main()
{
    foo<int, char, int>();
    return 0;
}
```

The compile meesage such as:

error C2672: 'foo': no matching overloaded function found
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void foo(void)' being compiled
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void foo(void)' being compiled
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void foo(void)' being compiled
error C2783: 'void foo(void)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'
note: see declaration of 'foo'

I declare the void foo(void), Why the error occured?
complier can match template  void foo(), but can't match void foo(void)

Comment: "void int void foo()" is not valid C++. The error message does not match the code. Try again.

Comment: The template version `foo<U...>()` require a specialization to stop the recursion. `void foo()` is not a specialization of the template.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your base case is `void foo() {}`, in your recursive case you're performing the following function invocations:

```
foo<int, char, int>();
foo<char, int>();
foo<int>();
foo<>();
```

Notice that the last invocation is `foo<>();` rather than `foo();`.
The compiler error is due to the fact that your base case of
`void foo() {}` cannot be called with the `foo<>();` syntax.